# Independence of $A$ and $\cos B$

Tags: statistics, independence

Quick question - if $A$ and $B$ are independent continuous random variables, does that imply $A$ and $\cos B$ are also independent?

Comment: Yes, and continuity of $A$ and $B$ is not needed.

Comment: is there a way to formally prove this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to use this lemma in the case $f=id_\mathbb R,\ g=\cos(\bullet)$.

> If $A$, $B$ are independent random variables and $f$, $g$ are borelian functions, then $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ are independent.

Indeed, let $E, F$ borel sets. Then,
$$P(f(A)\in E\,\wedge\, g(B)\in F)=P(A\in f^{-1}(E)\,\wedge\, B\in g^{-1}(F))=\\=P(A\in f^{-1}(E))\cdot P(B\in g^{-1}(F))=P(f(A)\in E)\cdot P(g(B)\in F)$$